# calibrate using "rms" with polspline error

Tags: r, cox-model, calibration

I am working on a cox model using the "rms" package by Prof.@Frank Harrell' and I would like to measure on calibration and discrimination. However, I am facing an error polspline during calibration which I hope someone could advise on how to solve this.

the cox model is fitted as this

```
model<-cph(Surv(tstart,tstop,event)~age+gender+race+cvdhis+smoker+dm_5+sbp+hba1c+ln_uacr+hb+weight+tc+ua+pol(k,2)+phos+ca+randz+strat(trial_recoded), surv=TRUE, x=T, y=T , time.inc =1724)
```

Then, to calibrate
cal<-calibrate(model,B=300,u=1724,maxdim =4)

The error I obtain is

```
Error in polspline::hare(S[, 1], S[, 2], fun(curtail(est.surv)), maxdim = maxdim,  :
```

not enough data
In addition: Warning message:
In Surv(y[, 1], y[, 2]) : Invalid status value, converted to NA

Can someone explain what is the meaning and what can be done to overcome this?

Comment: Well, the error message seems clear enough, you do not have enough data.

Comment: But I have a dataset of almost 12000 patients.

Comment: The number of observations may not be the relevant parameter.

Comment: What’s your class(dt$event), I didn’t see your dt object in the cph function

Comment: Hi Dr Zhang, i have specified as : tstart<-rep(0,nrow(df))
                                                      tstop<-df$time
                                                      event<-df$status

Comment: currently class(df$event) is "numeric"